# How to bind to a DataGrids Items property

Tags: wpf, mvvm

When sorting a Column in a DataGrid the ItemsSource property does not actually sort, the Items property does however. The ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection in my view model, but the Items property only has a getter so it does not allow me to bind it like I have done with the ItemsSource.

I have a ResultsView and then an ItemView; the ResultsView contains the DataGrid with my bound ItemsSource and the ItemView displays the currently selected item in the DataGrid. I have a next and previous button in the ItemView which allows the user to iterate through the DataGrid (gives them next/previous item in collection), but my problem is that when it has been sorted on a Column the next or previous items are not what they appear to be in the DataGrid.

e.g.

Unsorted Items: [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] - next and previous gives you the next/previous item as they appear in the DataGrid

Sorted Items: [3], [0], [4], [5], [1], [2] - if the user has [3] open in ItemView and hits next then [4] will open instead of [0] because I simply give them the next item in the ItemsSource.

The Items property holds the sorted ItemsSource so if I could somehow bind to this then I could give them the next/previous item in that collection instead.

```
<customControls:CustomDataGrid x:Name="GridControl"
                                   DataContext="{Binding CustomDataGridViewModel}"
                                   Items="{Binding SortedResults, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.DataGridResults, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                   SelectedItem="{Binding DataContext.SelectedReferral, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource MetroDataGrid}"
                                   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                   IsReadOnly="False"
                                   BeginningEdit="GridControl_OnBeginningEdit"
                                   CanUserAddRows="False"
                                   ColumnInfoCollection="{Binding ColumnInfoCollection}"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush3}"
                                   BorderThickness="2,0,2,2">
```

"The property "Items" does not have an accessible getter"

Comment: Please could you add the XAML (and ideally the code that shows the `ObservableCollection` being sorted)?

Comment: @pm_2 There is no code that sorts the DataGridColumns as this is done by the DataGrid I think.

Comment: You have a custom control - would it be possible to post the code for that, too (especially the part that handles sorting)?

Comment: @pm_2 I think thats irrelevant, my custom datagrid is pretty huge and just handles saving/loading users datagrid settings like column visibility, width and also sort order - but my problem is that when you sort a Column this does not sort the backing ItemsSource, instead it sorts the Items property which is no use to me when im trying to iterate through the collection as explained in the little example I provide.

Comment: Without seeing the code for the control, it's hard to say exactly why.  As I suggection, you could try adding a Mode to the ItemsSource (similar to the one that you have on Items); obviously, whether that makes any difference depends on what those properties mean to your control

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use Items and ItemsSource binding together...!

You have to use a CollectionVew and manage the sorting on it, then manage the paging....datagrid cannot manage sorting correctly on paged data source

bye

Comment: I've had a look into using the CollectionView and it might be something that will solve my problem. Will update this when I know more